# How to get a Disposable for subjects as subscriber in RxJava2

Tags: java, android, rx-java, rx-android

It might be a silly question, but how do I get a `Disposable` when subscribing a `Subject` to an Observable in RxJava 2.0?

For example:

```
observable.subscribeWith( behaviorSubject)
```

doesn't return a `Disposable`? How do I cancel such a subscription?

Or another example with `CompositeDisposable`:

```
compositeDisposable.add( observable.subscribeWith( behaviorSubject) ) )
```

This doesn't compile because `subscribeWith( behaviorSubject )` doesn't return a Disposable.

How do I unsubscribe / dispose / cancel properly with Subjects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not the first one to stumble about this. For example [issue #4438](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/issues/4438) is about it. Just wrap your subject with `DisposableObserver`. In another issue about `Flowable` someone proposed to use one of the `take*()` methods to complete the subscription.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand, I should use a DisposableObserver inside my xxxSubject.subscribe() ??